# avatarURL and displayAvatarURL doesn't work on my bot discord javascript

Tags: discord.js

I'm coding a bot for my discord server and I crated a command whic, when called, works.

Indeed, when an user types "!embed theTextToEmbedHere", the bot delete his message and send an embed with his message in it.
When I display the author username and all that stuff, everything works but when I try to display the avatar either of the bot or either of the author, nothing is displayed. 
I searched everywhere and all the functions given doesn't work.

Here is my simplified code (without the stuff which works) :

```
module.exports = async(client, message) => {
        //Already done all the test to check if the the command is called
        const membre = message.member;
        var avatar = membre.user.avatarURL; //Or displayAvatarURL

        var embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setColor(0x00a5ff)
                    .setAuthor(`${membre.displayName}`, avatar);
        message.channel.send(embed);
};

//Name the command after
```

When I'm trying to display the embed, the avatar doesn't appear on the embed, contrary to the username and all the others informations I want to display. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I finnaly found : I have to set the argument of dynamic to true

```
message.channel.send(message.author.avatarURL({ dynamic:true }));
```

Answer (score 0):

in discord.js v12 you need to add parentheses after avatarURL or displayAvatarURL

Like so:

```
message.channel.send(message.author.avatarURL());
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bot developer
And it seems you made mistakes in other places.. not where you think you did
You can copy and paste my code for avatarUrl revealing:

```
bot.on('message', message => {
const args = message.content.slice(P.length).trim().split(/ +/)
//If member wants his own avatar
switch (args[0]) {
               //The command:
               case 'pfp':
            const user = message.mentions.users.first()
            //If member wants his own avatar
            if(!args[1]) {
                var embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor('YELLOW')
                .setDescription('<@' + message.author.id + '>' + `'` +'s profile picture')
                .setImage(message.author.avatarURL())
                .setTimestamp()
                .setFooter(`${message.author.username}`, message.author.avatarURL({ dynamic: true , size: 2048 , format: "png" }))   
                message.channel.send(embed)
            //If member wants other people avatar:
            }else{
                var embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor('YELLOW')
                .setDescription('<@' + user.id + '>' + `'` +'s profile picture'+' ')
                .setImage(user.avatarURL())
                .setTimestamp()
                .setFooter(`${message.author.username}`, message.author.avatarURL())
                message.channel.send(embed)
            }
        break
```

}
})

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Typescript, it will complains that `message.author.avatarURL()` will return `string | undefined`

you can do this:

```cs
setFooter(..., `${message.author.avatarURL({ dynamic: true , size: 2048 , format: "png" })}`)
```